# Python failing in sub directory, but working in home directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualbox

I have an Ubuntu machine (18.04) on a VM. When I run python in the home directory, everthing responds normally, however when I run from a sub directory it is failing to import modules in the standard library.

The sequence below illustrates the problem

```
anon@anon-VirtualBox:~$ python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>import os
>>> os.environ['PATH']
'/bin:/home/anon/anaconda2/bin:/home/anon/bin:/home/anon/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
>>> import logging
>>> exit()
```

Which is the expected behaviour.

However when I go into a subdirectory, the same operation fails

```
anon@anon-VirtualBox:~$ cd GitHub/bikeano
anon@anon-VirtualBox:~/GitHub/bikeano$ python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['PATH']
'/bin:/home/anon/anaconda2/bin:/home/anon/bin:/home/anon/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
>>> import logging
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "logging.py", line 5, in <module>
   import logging.handlers
ImportError: No module named handlers
>>>
```

I do not understand what is happening here. Are there other environment variables which could affect this?

Also, this is occuring on a Virtualbox VM, and the same .vdi works normally on another machine? The host is Windows 10 on both machines.

Comment: Is there a file called logging.py in that subdirectory?

Comment: I think that is the problem, the files are getting copied into that did from a script, and one must be called logging.py thank you